# comparing two Dataframe columns to check if they have same value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have two dataframes,

```
new1.
      Name       city
 0    sri won    chn
 1    pechi won  pune
 2    Ram won    mum
 0    pec won    kerala

new3
    req
0   pec
1   mut
```

I tried,

```
mask=new1.Name.str.contains("|".join(new3.req.values.tolist()))
new1[mask]
```

I am getting,

```
 new1[mask]
      Name       city
 1  pechi won    pune
 0  pec won      kerala
```

As "pechi" contains "pec", it took this valu. but I want the exact match between the values not "contains"

my desired output is,

```
 new1[mask]
      Name       city
 0  pec won      kerala
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `\b` that means "word boundary":

```
a = r'\b(' + "|".join(new3.req.values.tolist()) + r')\b'
print (a)
\b(pec|mut)\b

mask=new1.Name.str.contains(a)
df = new1[mask]
print (df)
      Name    city
0  pec won  kerala
```

Comment: wow!, It worked perfectly, could you please explain what the first line of code does ???

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10138154/2901002) for explain `word boundary` (my English is horrible, especially for deep explanations)

Answer (score 0):

You need space in separator

```
In [1350]: new1
Out[1350]:
        Name    city
0    sri won     chn
1  pechi won    pune
2    Ram won     mum
0    pec won  kerala

In [1351]: new3
Out[1351]:
   req
0  pec
1  mut

In [1352]: ' | '.join(new3.req)
Out[1352]: 'pec | mut'

In [1353]: new1.Name.str.contains(' | '.join(new3.req))
Out[1353]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
0     True
Name: Name, dtype: bool

In [1354]: new1[new1.Name.str.contains(' | '.join(new3.req))]
Out[1354]:
      Name    city
0  pec won  kerala
```

Comment: It gives the same result :(

Comment: You can check the example flow now.